# How can I retrieve loginConfig programatically in Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

On Tomcat 7, I've set a Realm to let the container manage the authentication process. I've also set the web.xml with the corresponding `<security-constraint>` and the

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>MyRealm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/public/login.jsp</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/public/loginError.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
```

Depeding on the login protocol choosed by the user in login.jsp (direct or via OAuth), the flow might be re-routed to a servlet where I have to manage some stuffs before calling `HttpServletRequest.login()` if it proceeds.

If it doesn't, I'd like to re-route the flow back to the login page (ie `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()`.

**My question is : in my servlet, how can I retrieve the Login page set up in  web.xml programatically?**

I know the loginConfig can be retrieved in the `StandardContext` but it seems it's not accesible due to security reasons *(StandardContext is wrapped in ApplicationContext which in turn is wrapped into ApplicationContextFacade, which is the only thing I manage to retrieve)*

Does anyone has any clue on how to get that info?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no [public API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) available in current Servlet 3.1 version and thus also not in Servlet 3.0 as used by Tomcat 7. You'll need to parse the `web.xml` yourself to extract the information of interest.

Here's an oneliner to get started.

```
String formLoginPage = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("web-app/login-config/form-login-config/form-login-page").evaluate(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml")));
```

Doing it once during `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized()` or `HttpServlet#init()` is sufficient.

Comment: Shame for the lack of API. Thanks a lot for the oneliner though! It works like a charm!