# Access the value of welcome-file-list in web.xml

Tags: jsf, servlets, web.xml, welcome-file

Is there any way of accessing the `welcome-file-list` element in the `web.xml` without having to re-parse the `web.xml` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no public JSF or Servlet API for that.

Best what you can do is to grab JAXP+XPath.

```
InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml");
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
XPathExpression xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("web-app/welcome-file-list/welcome-file");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    String welcomeFile = nodes.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
    // ...
}
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), you can use its [`WebXml` utility class](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/WebXml).

```
List<String> welcomeFiles = WebXml.INSTANCE.getWelcomeFiles();
```

#### See also:

- [How can I retrieve loginConfig programatically in Tomcat 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700252/how-can-i-retrieve-loginconfig-programatically-in-tomcat-7/)
- [How to read session-timout from web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528373/how-to-read-session-timout-from-web-xml/)